# Make4ht with MakeIndex

Tags: makeindex, make4ht

When I us `PDFLaTeX` it's compiling fine. I would like to convert `LaTeX to HTML` using `Make4ht` but it's showing an error.

My MWE is:

```
\providecommand{\pgfsyspdfmark}[3]{}
\documentclass{acm-book}

\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{balance}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs,hyperref,listings,xcolor,colortbl}
\usepackage[inactive]{fancytooltips}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{makeidx}

\hypersetup{
pdftitle={A Technical History},
pdfauthor={W. Trcy -- Rose-Hulman, IN, USA},
pdfkeywords={Morgan \& Claypool},%
}

\newcommand\BookSeries[1]{#1}
\newcommand\BookAffil[1]{#1}
\newcommand\HalfTitle[1]{#1}
\newcommand\Author[1]{#1}
\newcommand\Affiliation[1]{#1}
\definecolor{titlecolor}{cmyk}{0, 0.7808, 0.4429, 0.1412}

\makeindex
\begin{document}

\chapter*{Preface}

Furthermore, legacy software systems are notoriously difficult to replace. As noted experienced by this author as a chief information officer, legacy systems take considerable effort and money to replace and tend to be built upon, rather than replaced. So, those working on systems for complex organizations are likely to have to deal with these existing software systems. US Social Security Administration still dependencies on legacy software further entrenches its use. Other systems used by the US government have software sub-systems.

\begin{quote}
But we [historians] remain largely ignorant about the origins and development of the dynamic processes running on those devices [computers], but primarily they will be histories of software.
\end{quote}

In the last couple of decades, software has gotten attention as a distinct topic from computer history. In particular there are wide-scoping works on the software industry. There's also been work on the evolved.

Software\index{Software|(} is a relatively recent technology, really only beginning in its own right in the 1950s. In the time since then, it's taken many forms, evolved immensely in the tools used, and in the purposes to which it has been put. Interestingly, software has become so varied and so complex that many current students of technology do not have a basic knowledge of the history of software. As a result, students and practitioners are sometimes repeating mistakes of the past and often relearning how to build successful systems. Additionally, some areas of software require a working knowledge of previously deployed software systems and their design decisions, such as software security\index{Software!security}. When reusing existing software, it is wise to evaluate the relevance of the techniques and assumptions that were used in building that original software. This book focuses on software as a technology and how it has evolved over time. We will look at the trends, important innovations, and events, as well as the ever-broadening world of software.

\printindex

\end{document}
```

EDIT1:

I have updated as per `michal` answered, but it's still showing error. MakeIndex Showing Error Image is:

[image: Make4ht Screenshot Error]

Comment: `TeX4ht` will works for standard class files like `book`, `article`, etc. Used `acm-book` was a customized one, so you have to write the `.4ht` for `acm-book.cls`

Comment: so is the question about `makeindex`, or about `acm-book`? it is better to make a real MWE, that doesn't show unrelated issues. if you have multiple issues, make multiple questions. this way is much harder for me to answer.

Comment: @michal.h21: This question is about only `makeindex` need to work in `acm-book` latex template. How to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TeX4ht needs extra command in `make4ht` build file to support indexing. See the [documentation](https://www.kodymirus.cz/make4ht/make4ht-doc.html#indexing-commands). The basic build file with indexing support can look like this:

```lua
if mode=="draft" then
  Make:htlatex {}
else
  Make:htlatex {}
  Make:makeindex {}
  Make:htlatex{}
  Make:htlatex{}
end
```

You can then compile your file using

```
make4ht -e build.lua filename.tex
```

There are also other options in place of `Make:makeindex{}`, for instance `Make:xindex{}`, which uses Xindex, modern replacement for Makeindex.

Regarding your error, it was fixed in TeX4ht sources. The fixed `latex.4ht` file is too large to get posted here, but you can update your TeX Live distro, and it should work then.

This is the result:

[image]

Comment: I have modified as per your instruction and still it's showing error. I have updated the Screenshot Picture . Please check and advise.

Comment: @Balaji I cannot reproduce your error. try to put this version of [latex.4ht](https://gist.github.com/michal-h21/c6eb4bc1a336281af43de5098753cb42) to the directory with your document, to see if it helps.

Comment: Thanks, now its working fine.

Comment: When I have used `\index` in the figure captions `\caption` it's showing error. For Example: `\begin{figure}[!h]
{\includegraphics{Figure_19.pdf}}
\caption{\label{fig:1.19}The Atanasoff--Berry Computer (ABC) with a drum memory\index{Atanasoff--Berry Computer (ABC)!drum memory@with drum memory} (circa 1942). (Source: Iowa State Univ. Library Special Collections and Univ. Archives.)}
\end{figure}`. How to rectify this? Thanks for your support...

Comment: @balaji sorry for my previous comment, I thought that your comment was under the JATS post. I was quite tired yesterday. I will look at this issue.

Comment: I have very much appreciate your support and prompt answer. Take care...

Comment: @Balaji I've found a fix for this issue, it should be included in TeX Live soon.

Comment: Could you please let me know how to solve this separately, and it's possible to send the source code to me?

Comment: @Balaji this version of `latex.4ht` should help: https://gist.github.com/michal-h21/c6eb4bc1a336281af43de5098753cb42

Comment: Now it's not showing any Error when I have converting `LaTeX` to `JATS XML`. But `CrossLink` like example `<xref 
 id="dx1-10001"></xref>` it's not generated in the `xml` file.

Comment: @Balaji they should work. I've made some more changes in the JATS output in TeX4ht and make4ht, so you probably have their older version. Please make a new question that shows the issue you have.

Comment: I would like to convert `LaTeX` to `EPUB` Conversion. New Question is : <https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/649009/latex-to-epub-conversion> and could you please advise which is correct way? `LaTeX to EPUB` or `XML to EPUB`?

Comment: @Balaji you can just use `tex4ebook` instead of `make4ht`, with the same build file to get the index.