# LaTeX to Epub Conversion

Tags: luatex, tex4ht, makeindex, make4ht, epub

I would like to convert `epub` file from `LaTeX` or `XML`. Could you please advise which is best way for that?

1. LaTeX to EPUB Conversion?
2. XML to EPUB Conversion.

`TeX4HT`?
`Make4HT`?
`Pandoc`?

Which is the best way to convert `EPUB`?

The `LaTeX` file is based on custom LaTeX template and having many `\usepackage` options.

My MWE is:

```
\providecommand{\pgfsyspdfmark}[3]{}
\documentclass{acm-book}

\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{balance}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs,hyperref,listings,xcolor,colortbl}
\usepackage[inactive]{fancytooltips}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{makeidx}

\hypersetup{
pdftitle={A Technical History},
pdfauthor={W. Trcy -- Rose-Hulman, IN, USA},
pdfkeywords={Morgan \& Claypool},%
}

\newcommand\BookSeries[1]{#1}
\newcommand\BookAffil[1]{#1}
\newcommand\HalfTitle[1]{#1}
\newcommand\Author[1]{#1}
\newcommand\Affiliation[1]{#1}
\definecolor{titlecolor}{cmyk}{0, 0.7808, 0.4429, 0.1412}

\makeindex
\begin{document}

\chapter*{Preface}

Furthermore, legacy software systems are notoriously difficult to replace. As noted experienced by this author as a chief information officer, legacy systems take considerable effort and money to replace and tend to be built upon, rather than replaced. So, those working on systems for complex organizations are likely to have to deal with these existing software systems. US Social Security Administration still dependencies on legacy software further entrenches its use. Other systems used by the US government have software sub-systems.

\begin{quote}
But we [historians] remain largely ignorant about the origins and development of the dynamic processes running on those devices [computers], but primarily they will be histories of software.
\end{quote}

In the last couple of decades, software has gotten attention as a distinct topic from computer history. In particular there are wide-scoping works on the software industry. There's also been work on the evolved.

\begin{figure}[!h] 
{\includegraphics{graphics/chapter_01/Figure_05.pdf}}
\caption{\label{fig:1.19}The Atanasoff--Berry Computer (ABC) with a drum memory\index{Atanasoff--Berry Computer (ABC)!drum memory@with drum memory} (circa 1942). (Source: Iowa State Univ. Library Special Collections and Univ. Archives.)}
\end{figure}

Software\index{Software|(} is a relatively recent technology, really only beginning in its own right in the 1950s. In the time since then, it's taken many forms, evolved immensely in the tools used, and in the purposes to which it has been put. Interestingly, software has become so varied and so complex that many current students of technology do not have a basic knowledge of the history of software. As a result, students and practitioners are sometimes repeating mistakes of the past and often relearning how to build successful systems. Additionally, some areas of software require a working knowledge of previously deployed software systems and their design decisions, such as software security\index{Software!security}. 

$$
{e}_{D}{({v})}=max{\{{D}{({{u},{v}})}:{u}∈{V}\}}
$$

When reusing existing software, it is wise to evaluate the relevance of the techniques and assumptions that were used in building that original software. This book focuses on software as a technology and how it has evolved over time. We will look at the trends, important innovations, and events, as well as the ever-broadening world of software.

\printindex

\end{document}
```

Comment: Since ePub is XML(ish) based converting from XML is probably easier, but XML without knowing the schema is so broad that it's almost meaningless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you already use TeX4ht, you can use the `tex4ebook` command, which is based on TeX4ht, for the conversion. I've only found that there are some issues with your file. First is that you use the `\Author` command, which is used by `tex4ebook` too. You will get an run-time error when you define it in your document, as it is already defined. For the correct functioning, you must use the following instead:

```
 \providecommand\Author[1]{#1\def\Author{#1}}
```

The `\def\Author` is used because `tex4ebook` needs the author info at the end of the document, when it saves document metadata.

I've also found that there is an issue caused by the `\caption` command. It can be fixed using this version of `nameref.4ht`:

```
% nameref.4ht (2022-06-27-11:59), generated from tex4ht-4ht.tex
% Copyright 2005-2009 Eitan M. Gurari
% Copyright 2009-2022 TeX Users Group
%
% This work may be distributed and/or modified under the
% conditions of the LaTeX Project Public License, either
% version 1.3c of this license or (at your option) any
% later version. The latest version of this license is in
%   http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
% and version 1.3c or later is part of all distributions
% of LaTeX version 2005/12/01 or later.
%
% This work has the LPPL maintenance status "maintained".
%
% The Current Maintainer of this work
% is the TeX4ht Project <http://tug.org/tex4ht>.
%
% If you modify this program, changing the
% version identification would be appreciated.
\immediate\write-1{version 2022-06-27-11:59}

   \let\NR:Type\relax
\let\ltx@label\label
\def\prf:label{{\ifx \NR:Title\:UnDef \else \NR:Title\fi}%
               {\ifx \NR:Type\relax \else \NR:Type .1\fi}{}}%
\let\NR:StartSec\:StartSec
\let\NR:no@sect\no@sect
\def\no@sect#1#2#3#4#5#6[#7]#8{\gdef\NR:Title{\a:newlabel{#7}}%
    \gdef\NR:Type{#1}%
    \NR:no@sect{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}{#6}[{#7}]{#8}}
\def\:StartSec#1#2#3{%
   \gdef\NR:Title{\a:newlabel{#3}}%
   \gdef\NR:Type{#1}%
   \NR:StartSec{#1}{#2}{#3}%
}

\def\:tempc#1#2#3#4#5#6[#7]#8{%
   \gdef\NR:Title{\a:newlabel{#7}}%
   \gdef\NR:Type{#1}%
   \o:NR@sect:{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}{#6}[{#7}]{#8}}
\HLet\NR@sect\:tempc

\def\:tempc#1#2#3#4#5{%
   \gdef\NR:Title{\a:newlabel\ssect:ttl}%
   \gdef\NR:Type{#1}%
   \o:NR@ssect:{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}%
}
\HLet\NR@ssect\:tempc

\def\:tempc[#1]#2{%
   \gdef\NR:Title{\a:newlabel{#1}}%
   \gdef\NR:Type{part}%
   \o:no@part:[{#1}]{#2}}

% this definition clashes with asmart and amsproc classes, so we
% need to skip if these are active
\@ifundefined{opt@amsart.cls}{%
\@ifundefined{opt@amsproc.cls}{%
\HLet\no@part\:tempc
}{}}{}


\def\:tempc#1{%
   \gdef\NR:Title{\a:newlabel{#1}}%
   \gdef\NR:Type{part}%
   \o:no@spart:{#1}}
\HLet\no@spart\:tempc

\def\:tempc[#1]#2{%
   \gdef\NR:Title{\a:newlabel{#1}}%
   \gdef\NR:Type{chapter}%
   \o:NR@chapter:[{#1}]{#2}}
\HLet\NR@chapter\:tempc

\def\:tempc#1{%
   \gdef\NR:Title{\a:newlabel\sch:ttl}%
   \o:NR@schapter:{#1}%
   \gdef\NR:Type{chapter}%
}
\HLet\NR@schapter\:tempc

\let\o:NR@@caption\@caption
%
%
% Keith Andrews <kandrews@iicm.edu> reported that \@captype as
% \NR:Type threw an undefined control sequence error. I think
% \@currenvir is safe, there is nothing special about \@captype.
%
% use of \index and \label inside caption results in a fatal error
% we need to disable them in \NR:Title
\long\def\@caption#1[#2]{%
    \gdef\NR:Type{\@currenvir}%
    \begingroup%
    \let\index\:gobble%
    \let\label\:gobble%
    \xdef\NR:Title{\a:newlabel{#2}}%
    \endgroup%
   \o:NR@@caption{#1}[{#2}]%
}

\let\o:NRorg@opargbegintheorem\@opargbegintheorem
  \def\@opargbegintheorem#1#2#3{%
    \gdef\NR:Title{\a:newlabel{#3}}%
    \gdef\NR:Type{\@currenvir}%
    \NR@gettitle{#3}%
    \defineautorefname{\@currenvir}{#1}%
    \o:NRorg@opargbegintheorem{#1}{#2}{#3}%
  }%

\let\o:NRorg@begintheorem\@begintheorem
  \def\@begintheorem#1#2{%
    \gdef\NR:Title{\a:newlabel{#1 #2}}%
    \gdef\NR:Type{\@currenvir}%
    \defineautorefname{\@currenvir}{#1}%
    \NR@gettitle{}%
    \o:NRorg@begintheorem{#1}{#2}%
  }%

% I don't know if this was useful for anything
% but we cannot use it anymore
% \AtBeginDocument{%
\@ifpackageloaded{listings}{%
      \def\:tempc#1{%
         \gdef\NR:Title{\a:newlabel{listing}}%
         \gdef\NR:Type{lstlisting}%
         \o:NROrg@lst@MakeCaption:{#1}%
         \gdef\@currentlabelname{listing}}
      \HLet\NROrg@lst@MakeCaption\:tempc
}{}%
  % bug [348]
\def\:tempams{%
    \gdef\NR:Title{\a:newlabel{equation}}%
    \gdef\NR:Type{equation}%
    \gdef\@currentlabelname{equation}%
}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/581856/2891
\@ifpackageloaded{caption}{
  \pend:defIII\caption@beginex{%
    \gdef\NR:Type{\@currenvir}%
    \gdef\NR:Title{\a:newlabel{##2}}%
  }
}{}


\@ifpackageloaded{amsmath}{%
     \Configure{@begin}{align}{\:tempams}
     \Configure{@begin}{multline}{\:tempams}
     \Configure{@begin}{equation}{\:tempams}
     \Configure{@begin}{boxed}{\:tempams}
     \Configure{@begin}{equations}{\:tempams}
     \Configure{@begin}{equation}{\:tempams}
     \Configure{@begin}{gather*}{\:tempams}
     \Configure{@begin}{gather}{\:tempams}
     \Configure{@begin}{genfrac}{\:tempams}
     \Configure{@begin}{measure@}{\:tempams}
     \Configure{@begin}{multline*}{\:tempams}
     \Configure{@begin}{multline}{\:tempams}
     \Configure{@begin}{overset}{\:tempams}
     \Configure{@begin}{smallmatrix}{\:tempams}
     \Configure{@begin}{split}{\:tempams}
     \Configure{@begin}{subarray}{\:tempams}
     \Configure{@begin}{substack}{\:tempams}
     \Configure{@begin}{underset}{\:tempams}
     \Configure{@begin}{xleftarrow}{\:tempams}
     \Configure{@begin}{xrightarrow}{\:tempams}
  }{
     \Configure{@begin}{equation}{\:tempams}
}

\let\T:ref=\::ref
\def\::ref{\@ifstar{\protect\T@ref}{\protect\T@ref}}
\def\T@ref#1{%
  \@safe@activestrue
  \let\::ref \T:ref
  \expandafter\@setref\csname r@#1\endcsname\@firstoffive{#1}%
  \def\::ref{\@ifstar{\protect\T@ref}{\protect\T@ref}}
  \@safe@activesfalse
}

\gdef\defineautorefname#1#2{%
    \expandafter\gdef\csname #1autorefname\endcsname{#2}}
\defineautorefname{theorem}{Theorem}

\Configure{newlabel}
   {\csname cur:th\endcsname \csname :currentlabel\endcsname}
   {\string\csname\space :autoref\string\endcsname
     {\NR:Type}#1}

\ifx \@currentlabelname\:UnDef
   \let\@currentlabelname\empty
\fi

\pend:defIII\@setref{\edef\RefArg{##3}}
\append:defIII\@setref{\let\:autoref\:gobble}
\let\:autoref\:gobble


\Hinput{nameref}
\endinput
```

You can then compile your document using:

```
tex4ebook -lf epub3 sample.tex
```

This is the result in Calibre:

[image]

Comment: when using `listings` package `epub` is not converting and raised new question <https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/649422/tex4ebook-with-listings-package>. Pl. advise.