# tex4ebook with listings package

Tags: tex4ht, tex4ebook

The below files is working fine with `pdflatex` and not working when converting to `epub`.  Its not showing any error also. `lstlistings` indent also not correct. How to solve this?

`tex4ebook -a debug -f epub3 -x filename.tex`

```
\providecommand{\pgfsyspdfmark}[3]{}
\providecommand\Author[1]{#1\def\Author{#1}}
\documentclass{acm-book}
\usepackage{balance}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs,hyperref,listings,xcolor,colortbl}
\usepackage[inactive]{fancytooltips}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{makeidx}

\begin{document}

\chapter*{Preface}

Furthermore, legacy software systems are notoriously difficult to replace. As noted experienced by this author as a chief information officer, legacy systems take considerable effort and money to replace and tend to be built upon, rather than replaced. So, those working on systems for complex organizations are likely to have to deal with these existing software systems. US Social Security Administration still dependencies on legacy software further entrenches its use. Other systems used by the US government have software sub-systems.

\begin{quote}
But we [historians] remain largely ignorant about the origins and development of the dynamic processes running on those devices [computers], but primarily they will be histories of software.
\end{quote}

In the last couple of decades, software has gotten attention as a distinct topic from computer history. In particular there are wide-scoping works on the software industry. There's also been work on the evolved.

\lstset{
    language=[1974]Cobol,
    deletekeywords={COBOL}
    }
\begin{lstlisting} [numbers=left]
//COBUCLG  JOB (001),'COBOL BASE TEST',
//             CLASS=A,MSGCLASS=A,MSGLEVEL=(1,1)
//BASETEST EXEC COBUCLG                                                     
//COB.SYSIN DD *                                                                
 00000* VALIDATION OF BASE COBOL INSTALL                                    
 01000 IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.                                             
 01100 PROGRAM-ID. 'HELLO'.                                                 
 02000 ENVIRONMENT DIVISION.                                                
//LKED.SYSLIB DD DSNAME=SYS1.COBLIB,DISP=SHR                        
//            DD DSNAME=SYS1.LINKLIB,DISP=SHR
//GO.SYSPRINT DD SYSOUT=A                                                   
//                                                                              
\end{lstlisting}

When reusing existing software, it is wise to evaluate the relevance of the techniques and assumptions that were used in building that original software. This book focuses on software as a technology and how it has evolved over time. We will look at the trends, important innovations, and events, as well as the ever-broadening world of software.

\end{document}
```

I have getting error in `Chrome`. Pl. find the attachment.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean exactly with "not working"? When you notice that the indentation in the listing is wrong this means that at least something is working, otherwise you would not be able to see the wrong indents. When I try your example there are some empty pages and a not very useful table of contents and indeed the indents in the listing are missing, but other than that the epub is ok, i.e., all text is there, the chapter title is there, the quote is correct, line numbers and boldface in the listing are ok. Could you explain the problem more specifically?

Comment: Maybe interesting for debugging: when opening the intermediate `.xhtml` file generated by `tex4ebook` in a browser (for me this file is located in `./[myfilename]-epub3/OEBPS/[myfilename]li1.xhtml`) then the indents are displaying correctly. So it could be either a bug in the `.epub` viewer (Okular in my case) or a conversion issue from xhtml to epub.

Comment: @Marijn: I have using `Windows 10` and unable to view the `.xhtml` file. Please find attached the screenshot in the questions. `Not Working` means it's not matching with generated `pdflatex` PDF with HTML.

Comment: The fact that it is not matching with the PDF output is expected - they are different formats. On which aspects exactly is it not matching, and which of those do you want to change? Also your xhtml output is interesting - you can see that the indentation in the listing is indeed correct, but also that there is an error (which I don't get when I generate the xhtml). Is your final `.epub` file the same, i.e., does it display up to the 3rd line of the listing or does it display the full file? Which viewer do you use to open the `.epub`?

Comment: @Marijn: I have using `Google Chrome Version 103.0.5060.66 (Official Build) (64-bit)` and `Calibre Version is : 5.44 [64bit]` both on `Windows 10`.

Comment: @Marjin: List Indentation is not matched exactly with PDF. I would like Same Output to `epub`. When I have opened `epub` file in `Calibre` it's generating full format without any error (like xhtml in google chrome).

Comment: I cannot reproduce this issue, do you have up-to-date TeX Live distro? The converted file is displayed correctly in Calibre for me, and `epubcheck` doesn't report any warnings or errors.

Comment: @michal.h21: I have using `Windows 10` version `pdfTeX 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.24 (TeX Live 2022)
kpathsea version 6.3.4
Copyright 2022 Han The Thanh (pdfTeX) et al.
There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
covered by the terms of both the pdfTeX copyright and
the Lesser GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the pdfTeX source.
Primary author of pdfTeX: Han The Thanh (pdfTeX) et al.
Compiled with libpng 1.6.37; using libpng 1.6.37
Compiled with zlib 1.2.11; using zlib 1.2.11
Compiled with xpdf version 4.03`

Comment: @michal.h21: Are you using `Unix / Ubuntu`? I have using `WSL (Windows SubSystem for Linux)` version is `No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS
Release:        20.04
Codename:       focal` and `TeXLive` Version is same of Windows...

Comment: @michal.h21: Could you please advise how to get same output as you get on my system?

Comment: It is possible that Ubuntu has older version of LaTeX files, if you use the version provided by it's package manager. It is usually best to use TeX Live downloaded directly from https://www.tug.org/texlive/, as it uses the most recent version of packages.

Comment: @michal.h21: But i have working only on `Windows 10` and produced files to here only windows based and not for `ubuntu`? I have installed directly from `tug.org/texlive` only (last 4 days back only)...

Comment: @michal.h21: I have tryed `which latex` and found `/usr/local/texlive/2022/bin/x86_64-linux/latex` and hope it's latest only.

Comment: @Balaji and what does `kpsewhich listings.4ht` say? isn't it possible that you have some other version of TeX4ht files installed on your system?

Comment: @michal.h21 `listings.4ht` version is `2022-05-22-19:43` and `tex4ht -v` is says `tex4ht.c (2018-07-03-10:36 kpathsea)`. It's correct or new to update? If update, how to do?

Comment: @Balaji these files seems to be correct. what about `kpsewhich html4.4ht`? do you get any `[WARNING] domfilter: DOM parsing of indexli1.html failed`, when you run `tex4ebook`?

Comment: @michal.h21: `html4.4ht` version is `2022-05-22-13:50` and Yes I have getting `[WARNING] domfilter: DOM parsing of Indexli1.xhtml failed:
[WARNING] domfilter: ...ive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luaxml/luaxml-mod-xml.lua:175: Unbalanced Tag (/span) [char=5838]` in `Terminal/Command` prompt. How to rectify this?

Comment: @Balaji that's strange, it seems that your files are up-to-date, so I don't understand why you get a wrong result. Maybe try it on another machine with clean install of TeX Live? And without WSL? Maybe that could make a difference?

Comment: @michal.h21: Okay i will try to new machine. Could you please confirm your system OS is `Windows` or `Ubuntu/Linux/Unix`. Which OS are you using?

Comment: @Balaji I am using Linux, but TeX4ht and `tex4ebook` should be platform independent.

Comment: @michal.h21: I agree with your points and if i have installed texlive on new system windows 10 the problem will be shown. Its correct? Thanks for your support and help... I will test on new system....

Comment: @Balaji I hope that if you install native TeX Live for Windows, that you will get no errors.

Comment: @michal.h21: `Native TeXLive means`?. Could you please advise this site is correct? `https://tug.org/texlive/windows.html` and download `install-tl-windows.exe` and run in windows. This is enough? Or need to do any other further installation...

Comment: @Balaji yes, this is correct